# jhipster micro-service elastic beanstalk gateway 401

Tags: jhipster

I'm having a bit of a problem running the jhipster micro-service setup on elastic beanstalk.  I have three separate apps/environments configured:

1. One for the jhipster registry
2. One for the jhipster gateway
3. One for the back-end jhipster service

Of course, these all run fine locally.  I've generated WAR files for each of these projects and have pushed those out (via the eb cli) to their respective environments.  I'm able to access the registry's UI and I can see that both the gateway and back-end API service have registered successfully.  Looking at the logs for each of these apps, there are no exceptions being thrown (that I can see, anyway).

When I go to access the gateway app (the angular app), I receive the standard jhipster error page:

Your request cannot be processed
Sorry, an error has occurred.
Status: Unauthorized (Unauthorized)
Message: Access Denied

Opening up the browser's console, I can see that - indeed - I'm getting back a 401 from the gateway app.

Any ideas here?  I'm not trying to access a secured page or anything - just hit the default instance URL.

Some additional details:

I chose the JWT option when generating the app and I'm deploying the *.war.original files that are generated w/ the -Pprod option (./gradlew -Pprod bootRepackage).

Both elastic beanstalk Tomcat instances are running:

64bit Amazon Linux 2016.03 v2.1.0 running Tomcat 8 Java 8

Yeah - thanks for reading.  Any insight/recommendations are appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure your gateway has a UI? You should not have the "401" page on this.... And are you running with the "prod" profile? You need to add it in your env variables (I know it's annoying, we are working on removing it)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Julien.  When I run the instance locally, I can access the default jhipster UI without issue.  I pulled down the logs from the EB instance and I can see this on start-up:  : The following profiles are active: prod.  I added the following line to the instances JVM command line:  -Dspring.profiles.active=prod  (so I think that's all working okay).  After a night, I can see that the instance is running - logging the following every 5 minutes:  c.n.d.s.r.aws.ConfigClusterResolver      : Resolving eureka endpoints via configuration. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @JulienDubois:  Interestingly enough, when I comment out line 109 (  .anyRequest().authenticated()) in SecurityConfiguration.java - the site gets served up.  Not sure what the implication of that change is on the gateway app.  Any thoughts?